# Pascal Quicksort - counting the total number of recursions

Tags: recursion, pascal, quicksort

I am stuck on my quicksort program. I need to count the total number of times the sorting function calls itself.

```
procedure quick (first, last, counter: integer);
var i, k, x : integer;
begin
   i := first;
   k := last;
   x := a[(i+k) div 2];
   counter := counter + 1;
   while i<=k do begin
        while a[i] < x do
           i:= i+1;
        while a[k] > x do
           k:= k-1;
        if i<=k then begin
                      prohod(i,k);
                      i:=i+1;
                      k:=k-1;
                   end;
       end;
   if first<k then quick(first,k, counter);
   if i<last then quick(i,last, counter);
   P:= P + counter;
end;
```

I tried this, where P is global variable and counter is recursive variable, first called as 1 ( quick(1, n, 1) ) . Sadly did not work. I also set P:= 0; right before I called the sorting (quick) procedure (I am not quite sure if it is correct way to approach the problem but it's all I could come up with).

Any ideas how to make this correctly and / or why my counter is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks overly complex. If you just remove the counter, initialize P with the value -1 (instead of 0) and replace P := P + counter with P := P + 1, it should work.

Comment: Isn’t that what the OP asks for ? He wants *the total number of times the sorting fuction calls itself*, so how is incrementing a counter once for each call not correct ? (apart from having to subtract 1 because the first call is not from the procedure itself).